# Can variant<int, string> be constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

From [cppreference documentation for variant::variant()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant):

> This constructor is constexpr if and only if the value initialization of the alternative type T_0 would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function.

The above says nothing about other types in the variant, so should the declaration `constexpr variant<int, string> v;` be valid if the variant must have a nontrivial destructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quote doesn't mean the declaration `constexpr variant<int, string> v;` is valid. To quote N4140 (roughly C++14 rather than C++1z, but the concept hasn't changed):

> **7.1.5 The constexpr specifier [dcl.constexpr]**
>
> 9 A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`. Such an object shall have literal type and shall be initialized. If it is initialized by a constructor call, that call shall be a constant expression (5.19). [...]

The declaration is not valid simply by the constructor call being a constant expression, the type needs to be a literal type as well. One of the requirements of literal types is that they have trivial destructors.